# How to do Google OAuth Sign-In in an Express API for an Android app?

Tags: android, express, authentication, passport.js, google-oauth

So we're making an Android app with the backend as a rest API built using Express and we need to have Google OAuth as the login strategy, but I'm confused on how the flow would work. I am expecting to use Passport.js for the Google OAuth in the API but how would I link that with the app, as in how can the backend api and the app maintain a logged-in session together, how does that flow work, since later the app will have to send authenticated requests according to the logged in user.

Would love it if one could link some docs/videos for this setup while maybe explaining like the diagram flow of data here.

Comment: This is a broad question. It's better to do some research and ask questions regarding the problems that you faced with proper code. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth

Comment: I did see this, @user667634, but I'm confused as to what it means with establish a session at the end, does it mean the regular session we lets say create with the express-session package? Would it work the same way for mobile apps?

Comment: Yes, a regular session that you can create with express-session package. It'll work the same with mobile apps, you'll have to create API endpoints to set or get session data.